# Isolate first order elements

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, string-manipulation, series-expansion

How can I isolate only the first order "h" terms in the following expression?

```
expr = q^2 f[1][f[1][f[1][x0]]] + q^2 h[1] f[1][f[1][g[1][x0]]] + 
  p q f[1][f[2][x0]] + q^2 h[1] f[1][g[1][f[1][x0]]] + 
  q^2 h[1]^2 f[1][g[1][g[1][x0]]] + p q h[2] f[1][g[2][x0]] + 
  p q f[2][f[1][x0]] + p q h[1] f[2][g[1][x0]] + p^2 f[3][x0] + 
  q^2 h[1] g[1][f[1][f[1][x0]]] + q^2 h[1]^2 g[1][f[1][g[1][x0]]] + 
  p q h[1] g[1][f[2][x0]] + q^2 h[1]^2 g[1][g[1][f[1][x0]]] + 
  q^2 h[1]^3 g[1][g[1][g[1][x0]]] + p q h[1] h[2] g[1][g[2][x0]] + 
  p q h[2] g[2][f[1][x0]] + p q h[1] h[2] g[2][g[1][x0]] + 
  p^2 h[3] g[3][x0]
```

The result shold be

```
q^2 h[1] f[1][f[1][g[1][x0]]] + q^2 h[1] f[1][g[1][f[1][x0]]] + 
p q h[2] f[1][g[2][x0]] + p q h[1] f[2][g[1][x0]] + 
q^2 h[1] g[1][f[1][f[1][x0]]] + p q h[1] g[1][f[2][x0]] + 
p q h[2] g[2][f[1][x0]] + p^2 h[3] g[3][x0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
expr = q^2 f[1][f[1][f[1][x0]]] + q^2 h[1] f[1][f[1][g[1][x0]]] + 
  p q f[1][f[2][x0]] + q^2 h[1] f[1][g[1][f[1][x0]]] + 
  q^2 h[1]^2 f[1][g[1][g[1][x0]]] + p q h[2] f[1][g[2][x0]] + 
  p q f[2][f[1][x0]] + p q h[1] f[2][g[1][x0]] + p^2 f[3][x0] + 
  q^2 h[1] g[1][f[1][f[1][x0]]] + q^2 h[1]^2 g[1][f[1][g[1][x0]]] + 
  p q h[1] g[1][f[2][x0]] + q^2 h[1]^2 g[1][g[1][f[1][x0]]] + 
  q^2 h[1]^3 g[1][g[1][g[1][x0]]] + p q h[1] h[2] g[1][g[2][x0]] + 
  p q h[2] g[2][f[1][x0]] + p q h[1] h[2] g[2][g[1][x0]] + 
  p^2 h[3] g[3][x0]
```

`Select` or `Pick` the terms that does contain exactly one `h[_]` at level 1:

```
Select[expr, Count[#, _h, 1] == 1 &]
Pick[expr, Count[#, _h, 1] & /@ expr, 1]
```

or delete the ones that does not contain exactly one `h[_]` at level 1:

```
DeleteCases[expr, _?(Count[#, _h, 1] != 1 &)]
```

all three give

> `q^2 h[1] f[1][f[1][g[1][x0]]] + q^2 h[1] f[1][g[1][f[1][x0]]] + 
>    p q h[2] f[1][g[2][x0]] + p q h[1] f[2][g[1][x0]] + 
>    q^2 h[1] g[1][f[1][f[1][x0]]] + p q h[1] g[1][f[2][x0]] + 
>    p q h[2] g[2][f[1][x0]] + p^2 h[3] g[3][x0]`

Comment: but with Count[p q^2 \[Lambda][1]^2 \[Lambda][
   2] Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalE], 1][2][
   Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalE], 1][1][
    Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalE], 1][1][\[Rho]0]]], \[Lambda][_], 1] i obtain 1

Comment: @Kowalski, you can try  `DeleteCases[exp, _?(Count[#,  λ[_], 1] != 1 || Not[FreeQ[#, λ[_]^_]] &)]` for  expressions containing terms  `λ[1]^2 λ[2] `.

Answer (score 1):

I like using [`SeriesCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesCoefficient) for tasks like this. Use a replacement rule to add a scaling factor `s` to each instance of an `h` expression, and then use [`SeriesCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesCoefficient) on the scaling factor:

```
SeriesCoefficient[expr /. h->(s h[#]&), {s, 0, 1}]
```

> q^2 h[1] f[1][f[1][g[1][x0]]] + q^2 h[1] f[1][g[1][f[1][x0]]] + 
>    p q h[2] f[1][g[2][x0]] + p q h[1] f[2][g[1][x0]] + 
>    q^2 h[1] g[1][f[1][f[1][x0]]] + p q h[1] g[1][f[2][x0]] + 
>    p q h[2] g[2][f[1][x0]] + p^2 h[3] g[3][x0]

While not needed for this example, the above replacement rule is useful when the `h` expression can be differentiated. For example:

```
{h[1], h'[2]} /. h -> (s h[#]&)
```

> {s h[1], s Derivative[1][h][2]}

Note how both `h[1]` and ``` h'[2]`` acquire the scaling factor ```s``. Also, in contrast to the accepted answer, the [`SeriesCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesCoefficient) approach works even if the expression is not fully expanded. For instance:

```
expr = (1 + q h[1] + q^2 h[2])(1 + p h[1] + p q h[3]);

SeriesCoefficient[expr /. h -> (s h[#]&), {s, 0, 1}]
```

> p h[1] + q h[1] + q^2 h[2] + p q h[3]

as compared to:

```
Select[expr, Count[#, _h, 1] == 1 &]
Pick[expr, Count[#, _h, 1] & /@ expr, 1]
DeleteCases[expr, _?(Count[#, _h, 1] != 1 &)]
```

> 1
>
> Sequence[]
>
> 1